# Lazarus: Missing FPC Sources/Directory

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, lazarus

I'm trying to install Lazarus for Ubuntu 14.04 and it's telling me that it cannot find a directory.

So I think some library or something is missing, but I don't know where to find it (searching online shows nothing unless you know *what* to search for) and don't know how to "install" it.

[image]

How can I install this thing? How do I get the FPC sources it's asking for?

Answer (score 4):

I will show you how to install lazarus per the official [wiki](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Lazarus_release_version_for_Ubuntu).

First, remove the current installed lazarus, like so:

```
sudo apt-get remove lazarus*
```

Clean up packages that the old lazarus installation might have left lying around, that might conflict whit the packages from the lazarus repository.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Download the lazarus key:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:11371 --recv-keys 6A11800F
```

Add the lazarus key:

```
gpg --export 6A11800F | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the lazarus repo to a `lazarus.list` file:

```
echo "deb http://www.hu.freepascal.org/lazarus/ lazarus-stable universe" > lazarus.list
```

Move it to your `sources.list`

```
sudo mv -v lazarus.list  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lazarus.list
```

update your sources list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install lazarus:

```
sudo apt-get install -t lazarus-stable lazarus
```

If you get a missing FPS/Sources, the documentation had this to say:

> WOW! You get a message: "Free Pascal sources not found". Just follow the instructions and indicate your Free Pascal Compiler source directory in the panel: "Environment->Options->Files". As explained earlier, on my computer this should point to "/usr/local/src/fpc-2.4.2". Note that when you change this folder, you should click on "Environment / Rescan_FPC_source_directory". - [Installing Lazarus - Free Pascal wiki](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Installing_Lazarus#Installing_on_Slackware)

---

**Reference**:

- [Lazarus release version for Ubuntu - Lazarus wiki](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Lazarus_release_version_for_Ubuntu)

Comment: I followed the answer and when I launch Lazarus now it shows me a messagebox saying that I need to downgrade (because there is another version? Even though I removed it per your answer). Anyway, the only option (other than Abort) was to Downgrade. I tried that and now it just says the same as before, missing fpc's, directory not found.

Comment: @jay_t55, i updated my answer ^

Answer (score 1):

In order to install  Lazarus try installing the below first,

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

After installing the above use the below command to fpc source.

```
sudo dpkg -i fpcsrc.deb
```

Once done with all the above proceed installing Lazarus. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why is synaptic needed if you are going to use dpkg? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me 4 out of 4 times on different installations of both Kubuntu 14.04 and 15.04...
From the lazarus download site, download the three *.deb files:

```
fpc-src_2.6.4-*.deb
fpc_2.6.4-*.deb 
lazarus_1.4.2-*.deb
```

install them in the same order as above:

```
sudo dkpg -i filename.deb
```

Ignore the complaints and errors.
When all that is done do this one last step - it could be a long one...

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

That last step will install and set up a ton of files needed to satisfy all the dependencies lazarus and a load of others needed for it to run happily.